# How to remove an existing item from a route request parameters? - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-request

I want to remove an existing item from a request parameters that passes in a controller.

Here's my controller:

```
public function getIndex(Request $request)
{
     // I need to remove a parameter from the $request here.
}
```

Actually, I want to dispatch a request in a controller but when I make a new instance of `Request` like this,

```
$new_request = new Request();
```

and add some fields to the `$new_request` like this:

```
$request->request->add([
    'id' => '2',
    'name' => 'test'
]);
```

Nothing is added! and the dispatch method can not yield a correct response with empty request!
But when I use an existing route request, every thing is ok, except extra items and I should get rid of them!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you need this?

```
public function getIndex(Request $request)
{
     $request->request->remove('yourParamName');
}
```